# How to make FCM as quick as possible on both iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apn

I am trying to speed up notifications delivery on firebase notifications.
Because sometimes it might take 10 seconds to get the notification.

Currently I am using this message to send notification with **admin.messaging().send(message)**.

```
const message = {

notification: {
    title: 'Immediate Notification',
    body: 'Important Message',
},
data: {
    title: 'data',
    body: 'some data'
},
android: {
    ttl: 1000,
    "notification": {
        "sound": "default"
    }
},
apns: {
    headers: {
        "apns-expiration": "1000",
    },
    payload: {
        aps: {
            badge: 1,
            "sound": "default"
        },
    },
},
};
```

I am not sure if the speed will increase.

Need Clerification:-

1) If I put  "apns-priority": "10" for iOS ? and priority high for android ? Something like this:

**headers: {"apns-priority": "10"}
"android":{"priority":"high"},**

2) If I set Time To Live to 0 ? **ttl:0** and **"apns-expiration": 0**

3) If I don't send anything in data object ?

Or maybe there are any other way to speed them up ?

Comment: its entirely on FCM service, Time To Live support max 4 weeks

Comment: You cannot speed up the delivery process, aside from it being server dependent its also device dependent

Comment: *"FCM stores the message and delivers it as soon as it's feasible"* - [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl)